# Generate database deltas for insert/update queries

Tags: entities, database

This is my first question here so kindly bear with me. I am a beginner to drupal and I wanted to know **where the fields for content types are stored in the drupal database**. For eg.

I have a content type **`post`**. I added a custom field to this content type called **`test_field`**. Now I want the database entries for this.

I need to apply these changes to an external database for which I have to generate the insert/update queries for them. I have already checked the **`field_config`** and **`field_config_instance`** and run the insert script on the external database for these two tables but still the custom fields won't reflect there. Is there any other table apart from these two which I need to look into?

**Also**
Is there any automated way or method to generate scripts for all the new inserts/updates in drupal for content, content types, taxonomy etc? Or is it even possible to do so? Tried googling it a lot but not getting a satisfactory answer. Thanks.